# Windows 7 virtual machine doesn't recognize a USB key with latest Virtualbox Extensions and a filter for that key

Tags: usb, virtualbox

I'm using a Windows 7 virtual machine on Ubuntu 20.4 but Windows 7 doesn't see the USB key. The latest VirtualBox Extensions are installed (6.1.16.6r140961, VirtualBox 6.1).

I try to connect the USB Key on a USB3 port, so I enabled USB3 support in the USB settings of the VM and added a filter for my USB key (which VirtualBox sees when I'm adding the filter). So I can add a filter for the USB key but I can't see it inside the VM. I tried disconnecting the USB key from Devices and reconnecting it, nothing happens. When I enabled the filter from Devices, the USB key disconnects from my host system, but nothing happens on the VM side. I can't see the USB in File Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by changing USB 3 to USB 2 in my VM settings, it seems like USB 3 on VirtualBox is buggy. Anyone has had similar issues?